# Xamarin iOS EventArgs missing first property

Tags: xamarin, binding, xamarin.ios, eventargs

When using EventArgs attribute on delegate method it generates event handler class with properties based on method parameters except the first one.

The first parameter is missing in generated event args class.

For example:

```
[Protocol, Model]
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
public interface TestDelegate
{
    // @required -(void)DidReceiveFrom:(NSString * _Nonnull)p1 withP2:(NSString * _Nonnull)p2 withP3:(NSString * _Nonnull)p3 withP4:(NSString * _Nonnull)p4;
    [Abstract]
    [Export("DidReceiveFrom:withP2:withP3:withP4:")]
    [EventArgs("DidReceiveFrom")]
    void DidReceiveFrom(string p1, string p2, string p3, string p4);
```

Then generated EventArgs class becomes:

```
//
// EventArgs classes
//
public partial class DidReceiveFromEventArgs : EventArgs {
    public DidReceiveFromEventArgs (string p2, string p3, string p4)
    {
        this.p2 = p2;
        this.p3 = p3;
        this.p4 = p4;
    }
    public string p2 { get; set; }
    public string p3 { get; set; }
    public string p4 { get; set; }
}
```

So it definitely missing p1 property. How to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Xamarin documentation this behavior is by default:

> For events that take more than one parameter (in Objective-C the convention is that the first parameter in a delegate class is the instance of the sender object) you must provide the name that you would like for the generated EventArgs class to be. This is done with the EventArgs attribute on the method declaration in your Model class.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/binding-types-reference/#EventArgsAttribute

So is seems that delegates in source library for which I was generating bindings does not strictly follow this rule and the first parameter is semi-sender in string form.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using `objective sharpie` tool to generate C# code for the Objective C API.

If so, then, basically you need to remember that it is a helper tool but not a 100% guarantee it will get correct C# code for you.

Regardless of that, easiest way to fix that is to edit the C# code manually and add this parameter if you miss it.

You're not showing your C# code for the `TestDelegate`. Might be that you have a first parameter as a sender and then all 3 other parameters as event args?

If that's the case, comment `[EventArgs("DidReceiveFrom")]` attribute in the C# API and re-compile bindings.

Comment: This is the iOS binding project so C# delegate code will be generated from above sample code. There is no place where I can edit delegate to use or not use sender as the first parameter. I just want to use C# events and have all parameters in EventArgs class then sender should contain real sender object rather then first event args property.

Comment: @awattar did you write this C# code or generated it from objc file?

Comment: Code was generated by sharpie tool but I've added EventArgs attribute because I want to use C# events instead of strong or weak delegate. Everything works fine except the first property generated from delegate method is missing in generated by binding library EventArgs class.

Comment: @awattar if you wrote EventArgs, why didn't you add p1 to the class definition?

Comment: I only wrote EventArgs attribute on sharpie generated delegate method in binding project. Then binding project generates wrong EventArgs class with missing first property.